# How do next.js applications optimize for mobile screens?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

[image]

I just figured out that since I built my app with Next.js, I can't use CRA's folder structure framework to build or diagnose my application.

Unfortunately, I'm completely at a loss at the moment with respect to how Next.js applications are supposed to properly scale a website for mobile devices. I've always been under the impression that it was the job of index.html to do that (which I've written, but my app can't seem to bother to find it or use it). I've looked at the default folder structure for a Next.js app:

```
├── README.md

├── components

│   ├── head.js

│   └── nav.js

├── next.config.js

├── node_modules

│   ├── [...]

├── package.json

├── pages

│   └── index.js

├── static

│   └── favicon.ico

└── yarn.lock
```

[source](https://github.com/segmentio/create-next-app)

but there doesn't seem to be a place for index.html.

My question is simply, how do Next.js apps optimize for mobile screens? Are they even supposed to have an index.html, and if so where? And how do favicons work, because I've created the static folder and put the favicon inside, but I'm pretty sure to have the favicon do anything, it has to be referenced by a file (conventionally index.html).

[repo](https://github.com/joshua-yan/summarAIze)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next has this [Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-document) component which you can customize to your own likings.
As their official docs say:

> Is used to change the initial server side rendered document markup

You can use it to customize your head tag content as you would do anyway in your `index.html`. 
Don't forget to add `<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` in head tag if you want your app to use media queries.

Next project is not supposed to have a particular `index.html` file. Instead, the initial page is supposed to be a component located specifically in `pages/index.js`.